# Optimize KDB query time to get rolling average price from each contributor

Tags: kdb

Each time a contributor gives an updated price I want to use this quote along with the latest prices of other quotes to calculate the total average at that moment.

```
t:`time xasc flip (`userID`time`price)!(`quote1`quote2`quote3`quote3`quote3`quote3`quote4`quote2`quote4`quote3`quote2`quote3`quote1`quote3`quote4`quote1`quote4`quote2`quote2`quote4;(21:11:37 03:13:29 15:35:39 09:59:13 04:34:15 13:09:01 21:21:55 16:54:39 04:03:04 18:22:39 17:05:44 05:08:40 07:35:50 15:46:15 17:32:29 19:42:47 03:28:48 04:20:03 14:16:55 09:02:12);86.4 84.4 54.26 7.76 63.75 97.61 53.97 71.63 38.86 52.23 87.25 65.69 96.25 37.15 17.45 58.97 95.51 61.59 70.25 35.5)
```

Desired output below

```
delete userIDPriceList,userIDComps from t,'raze {[idx;tab] select avgPrice:avg price, userIDPriceList:price,userIDComps:userID from select last price by userID from t where i <= idx}[;t] each  til count t
```

`userIDPriceList`,`userIDComps` columns are not required in final output

Performance is slow and looking for better way to calculate.

```
q) \t do[200000;delete userIDPriceList,userIdComps from t,'raze {[idx;tab] select avgPrice:avg price, userIDPriceList:price,userIDComps:userID from select last price by userID from t where i <= idx}[;t] each  til count t]
10152j
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you, please, define `fp3` in your example. It is used in desired output query, but is not defined.

Comment: Typo, now corrected thanks

Comment: Thanks. I think there may be a logical issue with the code. For example, the first two `GOOG` prices are `84.4` and `38.86`. Hence averages should be `84.4` and `61.63`. But above code gives `84.4` and `67.185`. 

I posted an answer below, hope it does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your clarified requirements, another approach is to accumulate using scan:

```
update avgPrice:avg each{x,(1#y)!1#z}\[();userID;price] from t
```

Igors solution is faster if the data is static (aka you can prep the table with the attribute once).

Answer (score 1):

Below code gives average of all previous prices for given userID including current row:

```
ungroup 0!select time, price, avgPrice: avgs price by userID from t
```

Just ensure that `t` is appropriately sorted by `time` before getting averages.

Comment: I think you can simplify this to `update avgPrice:avgs price by userID from t`

Comment: Agree! Thank you Terry.

Comment: This gives a different result to my desired output. I am trying to take the average prices of each userID as of the time of the record while ignoring any future records.     
  
`delete userIDPriceList,userIDComps from t,'raze {[idx;tab] select avgPrice:avg price, userIDPriceList:price,userIDComps:userID from select last price by userID from t where i <= idx}[;t] each  til count t`
 
  
Above gives the correct result but is quite slow to run. Assuming thier is a specific join I can use that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment to one of the answers, you're "trying to take the average prices of each userID as of the time of the record while ignoring any future records."

This query will do exactly that:

```
select userID,time,price,avgPrice:(avgs;price)fby userID from t
```

A query of yours (`delete userIDPriceList ...`) results in something different as @Anton Dovzhenko pointed out in his comment to your original question.

**Update**

After reading your comment I *think* I understood your requirement. Probably you could do this.

```
prices:exec `s#time!price by userID from t;
update avgPrice:avg each flip prices[;time] from t
```

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your answer. Perhaps I am asking the wrong question because the result from the query you are referencing is actually the correct output I am looking for. It is taking the last known price of each ID and calculating the total average for each and every record. Apologies for confusion but essentially the output is correct and I am looking to optimize it.

Comment: I updated the title of the post, hopefully a little more clear